# Can anyone buy my registered domain?

Tags: domains, security, domain-registration, privacy

Is it possible for anyone to buy a domain that I have already registered?  I registered a domain through Moniker and it has not expired yet. But it is displaying available through who.is

I can not understand why it is doing that.  Why does it not display as unavailable?

---

Now seems to me who.is server is not updated.

From  Farshad Ajdar suggestion, I have just tested it through http://www.internic.net/whois.html

```
Registrar: MONIKER ONLINE SERVICES LLC
Whois Server: whois.moniker.com
Referral URL: http://www.moniker.com
Name Server: NS1.BLUEHOST.COM
Name Server: NS2.BLUEHOST.COM
Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Status: clientTransferProhibited
Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Updated Date: 01-jan-2014
Creation Date: 21-dec-2012
Expiration Date: 21-dec-2014

>>> Last update of whois database: Sun, 21 Sep 2014 06:11:49 UTC <<<

NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the 
registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is 
currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration 
date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring 
registrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to 
view the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.
```

Comment: if you told us the domain, we could check elsewhere to see if it is just a glitch

Comment: check your domain with internic [http://www.internic.net/whois.html](http://www.internic.net/whois.html)

Comment: What do you mean by, “But it is displaying available through who.is.” Meaning how are you checking it? Also, when did you register it?

Comment: We need more information. Answers to @JakeGould

Comment: Who.is is a website. It is one of the most successful and popular websites of it's type. However, it can easily be wrong just like any of them. It is not necessarily up to date on any domain name which is a huge task and dang near impossible to get right without a fresh query.

Comment: I am afraid to flash the domain because I am not sure whether it is possible for anyone to buy it now. I bought it in December 2012. It will expire in December 21, 2014. I tried it to buy with godaddy or bluehoset, both of them told, it is already registered, but only name.com says it is available as premium domain. and give me option to proceed to pay $1000 for that. :(

Answer (score 1):

*Cached Results*

Most whois services online do not use real time whois information and use in fact cached results. This is because whois information rarely changes and there isn't a huge demand for real time whois services and the fact that administrators don't want the server being flooded with whois fetches on external domains. So in other words, your domain is not available and the problem here is the whois web application using old data, attempting to register the domain will display real time information and not be available.

*Run whois yourself*

Your better of discovering a online real time whois service or simply running the whois yourself. Below is how you can run your own whois on your domain for realtime data.

- Mac & Linux: `whois example.com`
- Windows: [Technet Whois](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897435.aspx)

Comment: Cached whois? Never knew, but that sucks.